# Main regressor becomes insignificant when including time fixed effects in a fixed effects model

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

My panel data contains 290 id's observed in 3 different time periods, the 3 last election years in my country. I am trying to estimate the effect of $x$ on $y$ with a fixed effects model. My first thought was to include both individual fixed effects (since my 290 id's are municipalities and assumed to not be homogeneous). However, when I include time fixed effects (time dummies) my main regressor, $x$, becomes insignificant. Im thinking the time fixed effects "consumes" all variation and thus leaving $x$ as insignificant. $x$ is a share of newly arrived immigrants in municipality $i$ for time period $t$ and is varying over time and within municipalities - with a large spike after 2014 because of the european migrant crisis in mid 2015.

How do I decide whether or not to include time fixed effects and also, is a FE model with both time and individual fixed effects called a two-way fixed effects model, and is a FE model with only individual fixed effects called an individual fixed effects model?

The two models Im trying to estimate:

1. $y_{it}=\mu_{i}+\lambda_{t}+\delta*x_{it}+u_{it}$
2. $y_{it}=\mu_{i}+\lambda_{t}+\delta*(x_{i2014}*d2018)+u_{it}$

(1) First and second term is the individual fixed effects and time fixed effects, the third is the share of newly arrived immigrants in municipality  $i$ at time $t$, and the last term is the error term.

(2) First and second term is the individual fixed effects and time fixed effects, the third is the share of newly arrived immigrants in municipality  $i$ at time $t=2014$ interacted with a time dummy for 2018, and the last term is the error term.

It is worth noting that $y$ is the share of voters that voted on a conservative party in municipality $i$ at time $t$, and that this party had low support across most municipalities in 2010 but gained a lot of voters in the election at year 2014. It also gained a lot of voters in the election at year 2018.

If someone could please explain the difference between an individual and a two-way fixed effects model, as well as give me some directions in whether I should include or exclude time effects, that would be greatly appreciated.